# Google started to open links in the same window

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, google-search

If I remember correctly, Google was opening links in new window for some time. Yesterday or today I found that it started to open links in the same window. I have played with my proxy these days.

So what is the reason? Do Google really changed a way links open? Or my proxy affected somehow?

Comment: Are you talking about links you click on the Google search site, or are you talking about Google's Chrome browser?  If you disable your proxy, does it go back to behaving like you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your settings might have been messed with, reset, or you are not logged in to your usual account.

Go to https://www.google.com/preferences and alter the **Where results open** setting:

[image]